# Filter for property in array of arrays of objects in jsonb column

Tags: json, postgresql

In my postgresql database, I have a jsonb column that stores data as follows.

```json
"Info": {
    "Groups": [
         {
             "Name": "grp1",
             "Type": "Simple"
             "Users": [
                {
                    "FirstName": "John"
                }
             ]
         }
    ]
}
```

It's basically an array of Group objects with another array of objects property `Users`.

I can query a group by name using the "JsonContains" operator, e.g.

```sql
-- get all groups with Type = "Simple"
WHERE attrs#>'Info,Groups' @> '[{"Type": "Simple"}]'
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to get all groups with users where a user's first name is John.

Here's what I've tried (doesn't work)

```sql
WHERE attrs#>'Info,Groups,Users' @> '[{"FirstName": "John"}]'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Note that I'm currently running on PostgreSQL version 10.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Users` is an array, so you need to provide another array for the contains operator:

```
WHERE attrs #> '{Info,Groups}' @> '[{"Users": [{"FirstName": "John"}]}]'
```

Alternatively you can use a JSON path condition:

```
WHERE attrs #> '{Info,Groups}' @@ '$.Users[*].FirstName == "John"'
```